# Rewrite NVL and select statement according to string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column, called `parametre`, which contains our parameters:

```
--option 1
TYP_SPRAC;PRIJEM_CISTY;DOKLAD;PL;MULTI;1;DOKLAD_EDI;DL+FAKT
--option 2
TYP_SPRAC;PRIJEM_VRATKA;DOKLAD;PL;MULTI;1;DOKLAD_EDI;FAKT
```

So i want to get a output `FA` or `DL`, according to string `PRIJEM_CISTY` or `PRIJEM_VRATKA`:

```
--joinning to another table... 
NVL(
    (select distinct 'FA' from import_par p 
JOIN import_doc ON p.partner=partner
where p.PARAMETRE like '%PRIJEM_VRATKA%'),

    (select distinct 'DL' from import_par p 
JOIN import_doc ON p.partner=partner
where p.PARAMETRE like '%PRIJEM_CISTY%') 
)
```

It works. But is there any "better" solution for this ? For example, `decode()` or `RegExp()` ?

Comment: This looks wrong. Oracle will complain about `=partner`, because partner is ambiguous here and you need a qualifier. (Or there is just one table with a partner column, but then you'd have `ON p.partner = p.partner`which makes no sense.) Once you add that qualifier, though, that will either be the table `import_doc` so as to join the two tables in the subquery on partner or it will be a table of your main query. Either way, you are lacking a condition it seems - either to correlate your subquery to the main query or to join the two tables in the subquery properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the two together to query

```sql
select decode(max(
       case when parametre like '%PRIJEM_VRATKA%' then 2
            when parametre like '%PRIJEM_CISTY%' then 1
       end), 2, 'FA', 1, 'DL')
  from import_par;
```